# Virtualenv Wrapper is installing both python version in the virtual environments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

The major issue is i only want python3.0+ version of python in my virtualenvironment. But when i create a virtualenvironment with mkvirtualenv  then both python2 and python3 gets install inside my virtualenvironments.
Images:

Bashrc Settings :

[image]

virtualenv settings :

[image]

Comment: *both python2 and python3 gets install inside my virtual environments* That's hardly possible. Why do you think so?

Comment: i have provided the pictures please have a look. I am also feeling the same @phd

Answer (score 1):

When you type `python`<kbd>Tab</kbd> bash shows all pythons in the `$PATH` — some from `/usr/bin/`, some from `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/`. virtualenv doesn't separate bash from the system, it only protects **one version of Python** from the global `site-packages/` directory.

If you've configured `locate` you can see all your pythons using command

```
locate bin/python
```

To limit the list for those in `$PATH`:

```
for p in ${PATH//:/ }; do
    ls $p/python* 2>/dev/null
done
```

Comment: where do i set this:
for p in ${PATH//:/ }; dols
 $p/python* 2>/dev/null

Comment: In the command line in the terminal. Try the code with and without a virtualenv activated and compare.